# Как в windows 10 sdk менять графические иконки либо найти таблицу кодов иконок?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

В оффициальном примере есть такое

```
<local:TabHeader Label="item 1" Glyph="&#xE717;" />
```

интересует параметр `Glyph`

Comment: пс вот кое что сам нашел https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx
тут их много, но не весь список(( например нет 721-го

Answer (score 1):

Нашел) Заходим в стандартное приложения для винды "Таблица символов" и там выберем шрифт Segoe MDL2 Assests в котором и будут иконки с кодами)